# ios Parse APNS no certificates - certificates not valid

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, certificate

I am adding parse push notifications to a couple existing apps. This worked well the first time, but on my second app I am getting: "Parse APNS no certificates - certificates not valid" in the delivery report.
I have gone through the certificate process over and over. This is driving me crazy. Does anyone know what may be causing this error or how to troubleshoot it?

Comment: where you are getting this error? In parse website or xcode logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was forgetting the provisioning profile step.